# Why isn't there a next operation on enums?

Tags: programming-languages, language-design, syntax, data-types, enum

In most popular programming languages like Java and C# there is a way to define `enums`, which are essentially datatypes with a fixed set of values, e.g. `DayOfWeek`.

The problem is, given a value, e.g. `DayOfWeek.Monday`, how do I get the next value of the `enum`, in this particular case `DayOfWeek.Tuesday`?

I realize that not all `enums` are ordered and there might be different kinds of orders for them (cyclic, partial etc.), but a simple `next` operation would be sufficient in most cases. In fact, since the set of values in a `enum` is fixed and limited, this could be done completely declaratively, assuming there is a means in the language to do so. However in most programming languages that is simply not possible, at least not as easily as it could be in theory.

So, my question is: why is that so? What are the reasons for not providing a simple syntax for declaring the `next` value for a `enum`? I suggest, in C# or Java this could even be done with a special *attribute* or *annotation*, resp. But there are none, as far as I know.

I am explicitly *not asking* for workarounds; I know that there are alternative solutions. I just want to know why I have to employ a workaround in the first place.

Comment: for exactly the reason you stated, if the programmer wanted a next then he should have provided one

Comment: I challenge your statement that a simple `next` operation would be sufficient (or even applicable) in *most* cases.  Perhaps it's been applicable to in most of *your* cases so far, but keep in mind that software (and enums) can model any number of abstract concepts.  This one comes to mind http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_.aspx.

Comment: Well, in *most* cases I don't use `enums` at all, by the same argument. But when I do, I wish there was a way to (optionally) define `next` declaratively.

Comment: I would argue that this type of situation comes up rarely, like when you're dealing with days of the week or months of the year.  In most cases, including uses of enum as flags, you don't need to know what order or what value they hold in order to program something using it properly.

Comment: That is correct. However I maintain that this type of situation comes up often *whenever `enums` are applicable*. In other words, most `enums` I have been using so far were ordered. Statuses, days of week, months of the year are some examples. Surely there are other kinds of `enums` like that "esoteric" `Boolean` in the dailywft article, but in that cases I just would not have to delcare `next`.

Comment: A quick check in Java implies you can reference enum members in the ctor of another member so long as it's been defined already. `Sunday, Saturday(Sunday), Friday(Saturday),...` could work. Alteratively, a .next method that's a little bit reflective would work. I think the real reason is because, as you say, not all enums have a meaningful or trivial ordering.

Comment: @proskor It is important to make the distinction between dealing with enum numerical equivalent and *order*.  Due to the lack of direct support in Java and in most languages, it could be said that enums aren't meant to give too much importance to this.  For example, if it is Monday, and I wanted to know what the next day is, I'd convert to day of the year, and then add one to it.  If you then need the day of the week, you should convert back.  Consider also that not everywhere in the world uses the days of the week as we know them, thus maybe a better system would be appropriate.

Comment: @Neil But You cannot just convert Monday to the day of the year (a date). Furthermore, the numerical equivalents of the enum values are not important, since that is how enums are implemented internally; what matters is the ordering relation of the elements and the question how it can be declared in the language.

Comment: @proskor The numerical equivalent of the enum value is very important if you must save/load it from a database.  What I meant by my example with the day of the week was to emphasize that it is not really practical to shift days of the week just once or twice at a time, since you may equally require to shift years at a time and you want to know what day of the week it is.  This sort of thing is very specific to this particular usage, and doesn't really fit with common usage of enums in general in my opinion.  More often than not, you use enums to differentiate states, not to compare them.

Comment: Sorry, but this gets completely offtopic. How to store enums in the database, how to do arithmetic with dates or whether enums should be compared or not has nothing to do with the original question.

Comment: Delphi/Pascal has `Succ()` and `Pred()` which do [nothing more than return the incremented resp. decremented value](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Simple_Types).

Comment: Java could've gotten enums "for free" if it supported algebraic data types or encapsulating values that aren't records (which are what Java classes are.) But it doesn't, so adding enums required special work from the part of the designers, and they have certain limitations as a result. They *could* add syntax sugar for a `next` function, but that'd require even more work on their part, and it's kind of a slipper slope; you could keep asking for more and more features until they have to add full algebraic data types to the language.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Why isn't there a next operation on enums?

It is difficult to generalize.

It is an decision made by each programming language designer / team.  But note that some programming languages *do* provide a "next" operation for enumerated types.

In Pascal, the `succ` function returns the next value of an enumerated type, and the `pred` function returns the previous value.  But this only works for classic enumerated types.  C-style enumerated types have "holes" in the type domain, and the `succ` and `pred` functions are not allowed.

Reference: http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refse12.html#QQ2-27-32

And, in fact, that gives a clue as to why many languages with enumeration / enumerated types don't have a "next" operation.  It is prohibitively expensive when you can't implement "next" by using integer addition under the hood.

---

Of course, in the languages that don't support `next` directly, it is always possible to implement it for yourself ... if you need it ... as some kind of helper method / function.

Answer (score 11):

In Java, the enum is a [reference type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3231684/289086) (don't let that little 'e' fool you).  You can do neat things with it like define methods.  A classic example of that is the `Operation` enum being defined as:

```java
public enum Operation {
  PLUS   { double eval(double x, double y) { return x + y; } },
  MINUS  { double eval(double x, double y) { return x - y; } },
  TIMES  { double eval(double x, double y) { return x * y; } },
  DIVIDE { double eval(double x, double y) { return x / y; } };

  // Do arithmetic op represented by this constant
  abstract double eval(double x, double y);
}
//Elsewhere:
Operation op = Operation.PLUS;
double two = op.eval(1, 1);
```

And you can see... yep, it has methods and so its not a primitive.  They *are* Objects.

There is also some magic that happens in the compiler as described in the [Java Enum Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html):

> The compiler automatically adds some special methods when it creates an enum. For example, they have a static values method that returns an array containing all of the values of the enum in the order they are declared. This method is commonly used in combination with the for-each construct to iterate over the values of an enum type. For example, this code from the Planet class example below iterates over all the planets in the solar system.

And I'll certainly agree that its annoying that this isn't mentioned in the javadocs.

The values that are returned from the `values()` call is an array that one can then iterate over.

```java
class Demo {
    enum DayOfWeek {
        U, M, T, W, R, F, S
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        for (DayOfWeek day : DayOfWeek.values()) {
            System.out.println(day.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

This prints out:

```
U
M
T
W
R
F
S
```

<sup><sub>Run this code at [ideone](https://ideone.com/7XTDSu)</sub></sup>

Why no next?  Well, given the ability to get the `values()` array it fills all the use cases for the `next()` method and is a bit more powerful.

If you really do want the `next()` method it takes takes a little bit of a hoop to get the array into an `Iterator` object (which is itself a replacement for the Enumeration type - see the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)):

```java
import java.util.*;

class Demo {
    enum DayOfWeek {
        U, M, T, W, R, F, S
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Iterator days = Arrays.asList(DayOfWeek.values()).iterator();
        while(days.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(days.next());
        }
    }
}
```

<sup><sub>Run this code at [ideone](https://ideone.com/3MZ1XB)</sub></sup>

So again, the reason that its not there is that its not needed.  You can get an array back from the enum quite easily and iterate over that, or convert that array into an `Iterator` allowing you to call `next()`.

There is also possibly the confusion that would be had trying to make the `enum` and `Enumeration` look too similar (they already look too similar) and trying to make the `enum` look more like the `Enumeration` with the same method calls  would further confuse things.  That said, this is just speculation.

Fundamentally, the Java `enum` is much like the C `enum` with the ability to have some methods on the side.  Its a bit more constrained you can't have them be specific numbers behind the scenes as you can in C:

```c
/* This is C */
enum cardsuit {
    CLUBS    = 1,
    DIAMONDS = 2,
    HEARTS   = 4,
    SPADES   = 8
};
```

People sometimes point to Pascal and say [`succ`](http://www.gnu-pascal.de/gpc/Succ.html) can be called on an enum there, why not in Java?  Pascal enums are ordinal types while C enums are not.  Java borrows from C rather than Pascal.

There's nothing saying that you can't define your own `next()` or `prev()` function. Its rather easy to do after getting around [an annoyance of forward references](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5678309/289086).

```java
class Demo {
    enum DayOfWeek {
        U, M, T, W, R, F, S;

        private DayOfWeek n;
        private DayOfWeek p;

        static {
            U.n = M; U.p = S;
            M.n = T; M.p = U;
            T.n = W; T.p = M;
            W.n = R; W.p = T;
            R.n = F; R.p = W;
            F.n = S; F.p = R;
            S.n = U; S.p = F;
        }

        public DayOfWeek next() { return this.n; }
        public DayOfWeek prev() { return this.p; }

    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println(DayOfWeek.M.next());
        System.out.println(DayOfWeek.U.prev());
    }
}
```

```
T
S
```

So...

1. The enum was borrowed from the C tradition of an enum, not the Pascal tradition of ordinal types
2. They didn't want to confuse `enum` with `Enumeration`
3. You have the ability to get all the values back easily with an iterable type
4. You can define a `next()` method that works any way you want it to.

Comment: I was thinking if the user just wants to have `next()` to know which enum comes after a given enum, having to iterate through the whole array looks somewhat undesirable from the algorithmic perspective, but I think it's doesn't really matter with enum (which guarantees to not consist of a lot of elements). A single memory addressing would fetch all of them anyway. Am I right?

Comment: Great answer, but the issue is really not about iteration. There is a big difference between *iteration* and, given a particular value, getting the *next* one. I would even suggest that these two concepts are completely orthogonal, i.e. they have nothing to do with each other. Maybe I am confused about the terminology, but, the way I see it, iteration is just processing all elements one after another; the order in which this happens is *accidental*, all that matters is that all elements will be processed exactly once. On the other hand, `next()` is all about order, which even might be cyclic.

Comment: @proskor Remember that Java draws from the C tradition rather than the Pascal one... but its not that hard to make your own cyclical next function.  Putting that functionality in for *all* enums would likely be a mistake.

Comment: @proskor 'the way I see it, iteration is just processing all elements one after another', so you gave them an order after all, accidentally or not it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @Dtex Sure, the order in which the elements are processed during iteration doesn't matter; however the order defined by the `next` operation does matter. So, what is your point?

Comment: @proskor my point is that the process of iteration produces a sequence, which has an order by definition, whatever that order makes sense to you or not. Now if i have the sequence [3,1,5], i think that the question 'what's the next element after 3?' has a definite unambiguous answer.

Comment: @Dtex Ok. So, how does it help me solve my problem?

Comment: @proskor i was just pointing out that your statement that 'There is a big difference between iteration and, given a particular value, getting the next one' is incorrect. But if you want to exploit this little fact to solve your problem, just define the enum so that the values() method returns the elements in the order you want, and use that to write the next function.

Comment: @Dtex The problem is that even unordered collections can be iterated over (producing some order, trivially), but that doesn't imply that the elements are inherently ordered. For example, I can model colors as an enum and iterate over them. But it doesn't make sense to say that the next color after *red* is *green*, for example). On the other hand, there are cyclic enums like `DayOfWeek`. Every element has a *next* element, but iterating over all elements would eventually produce one last element (which would not have a next element). So, you see, iteration and order are completely different.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15659/discussion-between-dtex-and-proskor).

Answer (score 3):

It is because of the nature of enums [(enum in Java)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html), [(enum in C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx). They are just fixed constants in the language, holding essential data (sometimes just their own names or just identity), not a kind of list. Therefore if you need this kind of logic (which might be applicable to many cases), then you actually have to create the logic.

Apart of being some sort of linked list, it can be singleton too (see: [Implementation Example: Using enum](http://java.dzone.com/articles/singleton-design-pattern-%E2%80%93)). It is more matter of use. Sadly enums (at least in Java) in this way tricker since you can't extend them or define an interface directly for them.

It is an open debate if it is good practice or not to use enums for some sort of constant list or singleton, the fact is, you can. I would vote against using it unless it is widely used pattern in the project. Smells like hacking for me if it is used locally.

Comment: But what if you really need a `next()` on enum. Say you want to know that August is an enum after July by calling `July.next()`. Then wouldn't you have to 'hack'?

Comment: Yes it is kind of hacking. I would recommend using APIs for these things, I regularly use JodaTime, they have such features, so you don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

enums are replaced with their constant values in the executable. they can not be traversed at runtime.

in C enum are part of the source code and the compiler replaces the enum with the constant int.

```
     // C source - enum gets replaced with constant
enum _tenum { A, B, C};
_tenum ft;
ft = B;
     // assembler enum is gone. only constant value 1 remains
mov DWORD PTR _ft$[ebp], 1

if (ft == B) {

cmp DWORD PTR _ft$[ebp], 1
jne SHORT $LN1@main
```

in Java enum are also part of the source file and the byte code generator replaces the enum with the public final static value.

Here is an explaination
  http://boyns.blogspot.com/2008/03/java-15-explained-enum.html

Comment: While the c/c++ compiler may replace an enum reference at compile time, that is not always the case for other languages: [You can declare the underlying type of an enumeration to be any integral data type (int, short, long, byte, uint, ushort, ulong, or sbyte). Enumeration members implicitly coerce to and from the underlying data type, allowing for direct assignments of numeric data to variables typed as enum. By default, the underlying data type of an enumeration is int.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/y94acxy2(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, there is a way to perform a next operation in both languages, though it varies between Java and C#.

### C#

In C#, enumerations are number types at their core.  You can simply perform addition with integers:

```
var day = DayOfWeek.Sunday;
foreach(var n in Enumerable.Range(0, 7))
    Console.WriteLine("Day of week: {0}", day + n);
```

*note: the above works the same way with day++*

Output:

```
Day of week: Sunday
Day of week: Monday
Day of week: Tuesday
Day of week: Wednesday
Day of week: Thursday
Day of week: Friday
Day of week: Saturday
```

### Java

Java allows you to define enums as full-blown object types.  As a result, you cannot simply increment it.  However, StackOverflow [shows several alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17664546/1148384).

TL;DR: there's a somewhat hackish way of incrementing an enum, but the suggested way is to implement a `next()` function in the enum.

Answer (score 0):

@dan-lyons answer for C# is okay, but it only works when:

- the enum is defined using consecutive integer values
- you know how many values there are
- you know what their integer equivalents are.

Instead, I would suggest using `Enum.GetValues()` and iterating the collection it returns.

```
enum MyEnum
{
    Value1 = -4,
    Value2 = 0,
    Value3,       // = 1
    Value4,       // = 2
    Value5 = 100,
}

...

// We need to use Cast<>() because GetValues() only returns
// a non-generic Array, which can hold any type of object.
var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).Cast<MyEnum>();
foreach(var value in values)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{value} = {(int)value}");
}
```

This will print out all explicitly defined values by their coded name and their integer equivalents.

```
Value1 = -4
Value2 = 0
Value3 = 1
Value4 = 2
Value5 = 100
```

You don't need to know the values or how many there are.

Comment: Not sure if it is equivalent but you can write ˋforeach (MyEnum value in values)ˋ which is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Providing this kind of behavior on enums would only facilitate a hack.

Enums are not arrays. They may technically be implemented as arrays but their logical meaning is a limited number of grouped constants that may be used in a type-safe manner. There is no logical sequental relation between group members.

An enum type definition is not a list, it is not even a collection, so individual members do not have an index, the order they appear in your source code is logically meaningless.

With their DayOfWeek implementation, Microsoft is being pragmatic and causing confusion as to what an enum is and should be used for:

> If cast to an integer, its value ranges from zero (which indicates
>   DayOfWeek.Sunday) to six (which indicates DayOfWeek.Saturday)

How convenient... and wrong. The proper way would have been to offer a Week class with a static method:

```
static DayOfWeek Day(DayOfWeek pivot, int offset)
```

Then there would not be a roll-over issue and one would not have to abuse the enum.

Answer (score -1):

Before Java there was C, C++ and Pascal. Enumerations in C and C++ could have wildly different values - they did not need to be contiguous integers. This had the advantage that you could define an enum for things like Windows message codes, which were a sparse set of non-contiguous integers.

(Borland) Pascal took the other approach, where all enumerations had contiguous ordinal values starting from zero. This meant set arithmetic was easy (e.g. Define Jan..Dec as an enum, then SummerMonths as a set of months (July, Aug, September). It was then legal to write **if (month in SummerMonths)...** It was also memory efficient, since enums could be bit-mapped.

For better or worse, Java went down the C/C++ route. For that reason, a next() operation does not make good sense.

Comment: C# went the C route, but `enum`s in Java are very different from that: they're not integer-based at all.

Answer (score -5):

Speaking for Java, what you are actually looking for is Enumeration (which is more like iterator) which has the nextElement support.

enum is a data type which allows variable to have a set of predefined values.

Comment: No, I think he really is talking about enum, not Enumeration.  He mentioned days of the week.  Such a thing is commonly handled using enums.

Comment: I think the definition says it all. If enum is a data type, it can take one of the defined values. There is no concept of next element  in that. Enumeration on the other cases are basically iterators over a collection of values where next makes sense. For a single value enum, next does not make sense

Comment: Datatypes without operations are useless. `next` is just one of the many operations which make up a datatype, like `equals` or `hashCode`. Whether it makes sense or not depends on what you want to do with the datatype.

Comment: Sorry proskor I did not understand your point. Primitive data types never had any operations.

Comment: *All* data types have operations, including primitive ones. Integers can be added, multiplied etc. Booleans can be `or`-ed, `and`-ed etc. The most important of all - the check for equality - is also an operation. What you mean, is that primitive data types do not have *methods* (like classes do, for exmaple), which are just means to *implement* operations in a specific programming language. But that is not a general rule. There might be languages in which primitive data types could have methods too.

Comment: +1 for you because you are so downvoted and that I might make the same mistake when the question seems to indicate an Enum class implementing Enumeration interface